# ¿Cómo representar 30 min al ejecutar la función setInterval de JS?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo establecer 30 minutos para que sea ejecutado mi query, lo tengo asi por el momento, esta bien?

```
setInterval(muestraReloj, 30000)
```

Comment: Tardas mas en redactar la pregunta que en buscarla, `setInterval` acepta milisegundos 1000*60 es un minuto. 1000*60*30 son 30 minutos en milisegundos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo entendido que tenés que colocar el tiempo en milisegundos, lo cual seria 1800000 ms